# Recommended Fixture for a 10 MHz to 40 GHz S-Parameter Collection

Tags: rf, measurement, high-frequency, s-parameters, characterization

I would like to characterize a range of SMD and TH components in order to show how different components have different parasitic elements that must be accounted for as frequency increases. I would like the measurements to be as accurate as possible, which means that the measurement setup is critical.

For SMDs I plan to solder the component directly to the end of the center conductor (I could do at start of the center conductor and trim off the excess so there's no stub and the component is closer).

[image]

[image]

My questions are:

1. Is this test fixture acceptable for characterizing components?
2. Should I be de-embedding these measurements? Or maybe I can calibrate with the SMA fixture with a short, open, and 50 Ohm load (instead of calibrating using an eCal standard).

All the measurements are single port, I'm only interested in the component's impedance over frequency. I'd prefer to go as high in frequency as possible, but am willing to settle for a ~10 GHz limit if 40 GHz proves too high to get correct measurements.

Answer (score 1):

> Is this test fixture acceptable for characterizing components?

Your proposal is reasonable for frequencies up to maybe a few GHz, but not for 40 GHz.

For one thing, SMA connectors are only rated for 18 GHz (or possibly 26.5 GHz in an enhanced version). For 40 GHz you could use Wiltron "K" or 2.9-mm connectors, which are similar to SMA but with a smaller coaxial diameter to eliminate multi-moding at high frequencies.

> Should I be de-embedding these measurements?

At 10 GHz, even the few millimeters of coax in your connector are going to introduce a significant phase delay, which is not a feature of your actual DUT.

So ideally you would de-embed this effect (or use a fixture that allows an accurate calibration at the actual location of the DUT).

> maybe I can calibrate with the SMA fixture with a short, open, and 50 Ohm load (instead of calibrating using an eCal standard).

For accurate measurements, you'll want fully characterized (and very nearly ideal) calibration standards. Such standards will have been measured on a reference instrument so that their non-idealities can be accounted for when using them to correct measurements of your DUT. An E-Cal device you bought from Keysight or R&S or Anritsu is almost certainly better characterized than OSL standards you build yourself.

Comment: "An E-Cal device you bought from Keysight or R&S or Anritsu is almost certainly better characterized than OSL standards you build yourself.", Ok, that's what I thought. 

And for the de-embedding, I will either see if there is a manufactures model, or see if I can model it myself, and then adjust the measured values accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well you want to study the effects of components ? I mean just the components because you didn't put the coaxial connector and the transmission line in the DUT. This kind of setup can be expected to work up until a few GHz with traditional materials (FR4, SMA). Above 10 GHz this become very tricky, and may require more advanced materials such as Rogers PCB, Connector.

If theses results under 10 GHz are of any interest to you :

You want to push further away the vertical line of what have been calibrated. To achieve such a thing require you to have a calibration set. At the frequencies you are using, you will have to make your calibration set yourself. The connector, lenght of transmission line to your component will have to be accounted for.
I guess you will basically print some PCB of some sort, solder the SMA the component and make your measurements. In this case what you have to do before making measurements is calibrating the VNA with your test fixture. Replacing the DUT with the 3 Following values to create your test fixture.

- One where the DUT is replaced by a 50 Ohms resistor (better 2 100 Ohms (the more the better)) use quality resistor 0.1% or less depending on the precision you want. And don't use wire-wound resistor which will be very inductive.
- One where the DUT is replaced by a short circuit, 0 Ohms resistor or a solder bridge.
- one with no DUT to make an open circuit.

The VNA needs these 3 cases to make precise measurements. Now you can study your DUTs, and have calibrated your setup until the DUT.

If you are studying at those frequencies I guess you already have experience in designing PCBs to work at such frequencies.

If not :

- The transmisison line should be made as short as possible.
- The transmission line should be fenced with a lot of via placed as close as possible.
- The SMD part footprint should have a few vias so the SMD is very well connected to the GND. (A via is an inductor as those frequencies. Putting more via will reduce this effect)
- SMA connector may not have a high enough operating frequency for your test (Some other answer have treated this problem)